# Serialize instace of autogenerated class to XML string

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have got the following class generated from xsd.exe. Thats why i can't just add something like `[XML Attribute("...")]` to the code.

```
public partial class MethodCheckType {

    private WebServiceType[] webServiceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WebService")]
    public WebServiceType[] WebService {
        get {
            return this.webServiceField;
        }
        set {
            this.webServiceField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class WebServiceType {

    private string uRLField;

    private string parameterField;

    private string returnValueField;

    private CredentialsType credentialsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string URL {
        get {
            return this.uRLField;
        }
        set {
            this.uRLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Parameter {
        get {
            return this.parameterField;
        }
        set {
            this.parameterField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ReturnValue {
        get {
            return this.returnValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.returnValueField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public CredentialsType Credentials {
        get {
            return this.credentialsField;
        }
        set {
            this.credentialsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe i have to change my XSD file and then i had to write this in the class code again.

For understanding it better: I want to proof another method (the method "ReadXml" below) to work correct.

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads an XML File in an array of WebServiceType objects.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The filename to read.</param>
/// <returns>An array of WebServiceType Objects.</returns>
public static WebServiceType[] ReadXml(string path)
{
    // Is the path NOT a valic UNC path?
    if (!IsValidPath(path))
    {
        Console.Write(MethodCheck.Properties.Resources.ERR003);
        return null;
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MethodCheckType));
    MethodCheckType output = null;
    StringReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        reader = new StringReader(path);
        output = (MethodCheckType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }

    return output.WebService;
}
```

To check the ReadXml method i have to write a method (for unti tests) which takes as params an array of WebServiceType objects an returns a string. I have no idea how to write this method. Below is a sample string:

[image: Sample Xml Document]

**Edit:**
This text seems to be hard to understand. I will try to formulate it in a clearer way:
I already have got the ReadXml method. To proof whether it works correct or not i coded a test method:

```
 /// <summary>
 ///A test for ReadXml
 ///</summary>
 [TestMethod()]
 public void ReadXmlTest2()
 {
     string path = @"C:\Users\pp-admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Methodenpruefung der Webservices\Methodenpruefung\Methodenpruefung\BeispielXmlDatei.xml";
     string expected = testXMLFile;
     string  actual;
     WebServiceType[] xmlSerialized = WebserviceReader.ReadXml(path);
     // Deserialisieren des XML Objekts um einen String zu bekommen
     actual = WebServiceType.SerializeToXml(xmlSerialized);
     Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
     Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
 }
```

The method SerializeToXml has to take an array of WebServiceType objects, but it should return a complete XML string like its shown in the sample.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method deserializes an arrayof WebServiceType objects into a XML string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">The WebServiceType object to deserialize.</param>
/// <returns>A XML string.</returns>
public static string SerializeToXml(WebServiceType[] services)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MethodCheckType));
    MemoryStream ms = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(ms);
        Object t = (Object)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Maybe on my side is some confusion what "serialization" and "deserialization" means, sorry about that. But i hope now it is a bit clearer what i exactly mean.

**Edit:**
First thanks to the answers below. The SerializeToXml Method seems to work now.

There is another problem: With the following code i get an error:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "MethodCheck")]
public partial class MethodCheckType { }
```

The error message is:

> Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. Its only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.

Could there be another using declaration i have to add? Or why this does not work?

Comment: Can you see picture of my sample string? I can't.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the whitespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean that you need a method that takes an array of `WebServiceType` and *serialises* them to an XML string, so that ReadXml can deserialise them and you test that the objects you get back are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to *serialise* (turn objects into some representation that can be stored, like a string), not *deserialise* (turn a string or some other representation into objects in memory).

The [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448270/351301) already gives you most of what you need.

```
public static string SerializeToXml(WebServiceType[] webServices)
{
    // Make a MethodCheck object to hold the services.
    // This ensures that you get a top-level <MethodCheck> tag in the XML.
    MethodCheckType container = new MethodCheckType();
    container.WebService = webServices;

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MethodCheckType));
        // Note that you're serializing, not deserializing.
        serializer.Serialize(writer, container);
        writer.Flush();
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

However, there are two things to be careful of here:

- Comparing two XML strings might not give you the results you want. Even if the XML is technically identical, even the smallest difference in *insignificant* whitespace will cause the string comparison to return false. For example, these two blocks of XML will fail a string comparison, even though the XML has the same structure:

```xml
<a><b>Text</b></a>

<a>
    <b>Text</b>
</a>
```

- The names of the tags might not be right. The *tags* are called `<MethodCheck>` and `<WebService>`. The *types* are called `MethodCheckType` and `WebServiceType`, and they have no `[XmlElement]` attributes to give them different *serialised* names, which I think is what you referred to in the beginning of your answer. Because xsd.exe generates partial classes for you, you can create **another source file** that *extends* the generated classes. Example:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "WebService")]
partial class WebServiceType
{
}

// And the same for MethodCheckType.
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization and deserialization play a major role in Distributed architecture. To just make it simple you can say that serialization is transferring an object to string in a manner that it can be stored or transferred from one machine to another and vice versa process is deserialization.