# How do I go from a DTD file to .NET code that uses it ?

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl, dtd

The company I am working with provides no samples of any kind. Just a DTD file. I am familiar with getting a WSDL file and letting VS generate the proxy code.

What is the easiest way to get up and running in C#.NET with nothing but a DTD file?  Is there some other tool that will generate proxy code or something ? I don't know where to start

Comment: have you tried googling `C# DTD processing or Parsing` here is something that could give you some ideas https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z2adhb2f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I think I see the basics but before I go do everything by hand.. Is there any sort of tool that can wrap an API around it with methods to request/get response ? Otherwise it seems I have to manually create a piece of XML that carefully follows the structure in the DTD?

Answer (score 2):

I got it. It is

1. Convert it to XSD
2. Use xsd.exe to convert it to classes.
3. Convert an object to xml using something like this

[Convert an object to an XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447529/convert-an-object-to-an-xml-string)