# Convert xml string to C# object

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my XML code.

```
<programs>
<program>
    <ProgrameName>Test</ProgrameName>
    <deviceTypes>
        <DeviceType>POS</DeviceType>
        <deviceTargets>
            <DeviceNames>
                <DeviceName>POS0001</DeviceName>
                <DeviceName>POS0001</DeviceName>
                <DeviceName>POS0001</DeviceName>
            </DeviceNames>  
            <AttemptToIstall>True</AttemptToIstall>
            <Mandetory>False</Mandetory>
            <SkipIfOffline>False</SkipIfOffline>
        </deviceTargets>
        <AttemptToIstall>True</AttemptToIstall>
        <Mandatory>False</Mandatory>
        <SkipIfOffline>False</SkipIfOffline>
    </deviceTypes>      
</program>
```

please help me to write C# code using XmlSerializer.I want to create an object and serialize those object according to above XML.

below are my C# class.

```
 public class ProgramP
{
    public string ProgrameName { get; set; }
    [XmlRoot("")]
    public class DeviceTypes
    {
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        [XmlRoot("")]
        public class DeviceTargets
        {
            public string DeviceNames { get; set; }
            public string AttemptToIstall { get; set; }
            public string Mandetory { get; set; }
            public string SkipIfOffline { get; set; }
        }
        [XmlElement("DeviceTargets")]
        public DeviceTargets[] ArDeviceTargets { get; set; }
        public string AttemptToIstall { get; set; }
        public string Mandetory { get; set; }
        public string SkipIfOffline { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlElement("DeviceTypes")]
    public DeviceTypes[] ArDeviceType { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my C# code.can any body please correct me or suggest me where i have to add more class or how can i arrange my class so that i can get above XML as output.

```
public void ExportClass(string strFilePathExportedXML)
    {
        ProgramP ProgramP = new ProgramP
        {
            ProgrameName = "Test",
            ArDeviceType = new ProgramP.DeviceTypes[] {
            new ProgramP.DeviceTypes {
                DeviceType = "POS1",
                  AttemptToIstall="True",
                            Mandetory="True",
                            SkipIfOffline="True",
                ArDeviceTargets = new ProgramP.DeviceTypes.DeviceTargets[] {
                    new ProgramP.DeviceTypes.DeviceTargets {
                        DeviceNames="POS01",
                        AttemptToIstall="True",
                        Mandetory="True",
                        SkipIfOffline="True"
                    },
                     new ProgramP.DeviceTypes.DeviceTargets {
                         DeviceNames="POS02",
                        AttemptToIstall="True",
                        Mandetory="True",
                        SkipIfOffline="True"
                    }
                }               
        };


 TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strFilePathExportedXML);
        XmlSerializer serializerOut = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProgramP));
        serializerOut.Serialize(writer, ProgramP);
        writer.Close();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

After mapping, you can use this:

```
public static YourClass LoadFromXMLString(string xmlText)
{
    var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass ));
    return serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as YourClass ;
}
```

From this topic: [Convert Xml to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447529/convert-an-object-to-an-xml-string)

Comment: Simple and efficient, thanks!